# How to load my own script into Firefox extension's tab?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to alter behavior of a Firefox' extensions tab (one of the `moz-extension://` URLs). I tried to paste the following into dev console:

```
const script =
    document.querySelector("script#updater_script")
    ||
    document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://127.0.0.1:1337/tampermonkey_plugin.js";
script.type = "module";
script.id = "updater_script";

if(script.parentNode == null)
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

But I get an error:

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://127.0.0.1:1337/tampermonkey_plugin.js (“script-src”).

How do I avoid this security error? Can I tell Firefox to trust localhost in this case? Or can the localhost server send a header that will allow the script to be loaded?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the code of a _different_ extension, or your own extension?

Comment: @seaturtle A different extension, one that I have installed through the firefox addon search.

Comment: Hm. My guess is that it wouldn't be possible; in fact, it'd be kind of scary if it is possible. Is the extension you want to modify open-source?

Comment: @seaturtle I don't know, but I don't want to fork it, just tweak it's UI a little. Specifically, I want to add an option for reloading Tampermonkey script from a file automatically.

Comment: Well, forking it for yourself (you don't have to give it to anyone) is probably the best option. Don't worry, it's not too difficult (well, except for reading other people's code, but that's pretty standard). Of course, if the extension you want _isn't_ open-source, you're out of luck.

Comment: OK, looks like Tampermonkey is *not* open-source (the [license on AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/license/) is just a copyright statement, and its [EULA](http://tampermonkey.net/eula.php) is _decidedly_ closed). But Greasemonkey is, if you want to go with that instead. If you're feeling bold, you can also talk to the author about open-sourcing Tampermonkey, but there's no guarantee that they'd be interested.